# How to perform 301 before force_ssl? Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, middleware

I need to make http://example.com go to https://www.example.com.  right now it's warning in the browser. I followed: http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2011/05/configuring-rails-3-https-ssl/

loading from /lib/middleware (Rails 3.1)

```
class WwwMiddlewareRedirect
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    request = Rack::Request.new(env)
    if request.host.starts_with?("example.com")
      [301, {"Location" => request.url.sub("//", "//www.")}, self]
    else
      @app.call(env)
    end
  end

  def each(&block)
  end
end
```

production env

```
Example::Application.configure do

  config.force_ssl = true

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  config.middleware.use "WwwMiddlewareRedirect"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get your webserver to do the redirect, that's usually best.  If you're on Heroku or a similar platform where you can't get the webserver to redirect for you, make these changes:

Change the middleware line to be:

```
config.middleware.insert_before Rack::SSL, "WwwMiddlewareRedirect"
```

Then in your gemfile, include:

```
gem 'rack-ssl', :require => 'rack/ssl'
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, I think you are using the < 3.1 instructions for a 3.1 app. In 3.1 you only need to set force_ssl to true and it will result in the behavior you desire.

Comment: the certificate is for www.example.com and not example.com, e.g. https://amazon.com

Comment: Ah I see. Well FWIW, I would probably do this redirect at the webserver (nginx) level. (But I realize I don't know your exact situation so maybe that's not ideal)

Comment: Also, certs usually come for both example.com and www.example.com... i think even the cheap ones.

Comment: Heroku charges $100/mth for root domain based ssl cert support.